# HTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am wanting to insert HTML divs into Javascript - but am having trouble working out how. Basically, I am looking to add ad tags depending on the size of the inner window size. This script is working for my adsense ads, but i need it to work for another solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if (width >= 630) {
    [insert div # 1 here]
} else if (width < 630) {
    [insert div # 2 here]
}
// ]]></script>
```

Both divs are in the following format - and are referenced by another script in the header:

```
<div id="exampleone" class="ABCXYZ" data-serve="abcdefg">
<div id="exampletwo" class="ABCXYZ" data-serve="abcdefh">
```

Help much appreciated!

UPDATE: This is what I am currently trying - but to no avail

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var body = document.getElementsByTagName ("body")[0];
if (with >= 630) {
    body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML + "<div id='exampleone' class='ABCXYZ' data-serve='abcdefg'>";
else if (width < 630) {
    body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML + "<div id='exampletwo' class='ABCXYZ' data-serve='abcdefh'>";
}
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: Where are you placing the dividers in respect to the rest of your html? For instance, you could use JavaScript to append them to another element. You could also set the innerHTML of an element to the divider in question.

Comment: Do you just need the code to insert the div?  Are you getting the right width you're looking for?  What kind of structure are you looking to build into this div later and how will you be doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to insert the div into the body element, you could do something like this:

```
// there should be only one <body> tag, so hardcoding [0] should be okay
var body = document.getElementsByTagName ("body")[0];
// or if your body (or other element) has an id, try this:
var body = document.getElementById ("body-id-value");

if (with >= 630) {
    body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML + "<div id='exampleone' class='ABCXYZ' data-serve='abcdefg'>";
else if (width < 630) {
    body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML + "<div id='exampletwo' class='ABCXYZ' data-serve='abcdefh'>";
}
```

This will insert the div at the bottom of all other content in the body tag. If you want the div to be before all other content, add the current HTML after the div:

```
body.innerHTML = "<div id='exampletwo' class='ABCXYZ' data-serve='abcdefh'>" + body.innerHTML;
```

If you want to insert the div someplace in the middle of other content I'd recommend using a javascript library such as jQuery, otherwise it's a lot more work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I've tried to get it to work, but to no avail. I'll paste the code in total that I have used as an answer below:

Comment: If you do `body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML + "foobar"` do you still get nothing showing up?

Comment: Unfortunately still nothing comes up with that

Comment: That either means there's an error someplace in the javascript (have you checked the browser's console?) or the body tag is clipped and not showing all of the content (again, check the browser's development tools - there should be a way to inspect elements to see the HTML. Note, don't just right-click and use "view source" since that won't show anything dynamically generated.)